# What is the idiomatic way to exhaust a Queue in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, queue

Say I have a queue, and I want to exhaust it. The way I would do it is something like

```
void emptyQueue(Queue<T> q) {
  T i;
  while ((i = q.poll()) != null)
    consume(i);
}
```

but this feels like an archaic method.

I would like something more like the `forEach` method. It is, of course, present - the `Queue` being a `Collection` - but it iterates over the elements, rather than consuming them.

Ideally, I would have liked a `pollEach` method on `Queue` - but I can't seem to find anything appropriate.

How do you write this kind of code?

Comment: You do add a consumer to the `forEach`... `q.forEach(this::consume);` should be equivalent to your code.

Comment: @daniu that does not remove the elements from the queue as they are consumed though.

Comment: you could change the `while` to: `for(T ti= null; (i = queue.poll()) != null; ){...}` which might be slightly nicer, because the `i` variable is only available inside the for scope

Comment: If your queue inherits from `AbstractQueue` you can simply use the `clear()` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use your own generator that calls `poll()` on the queue:

```
Stream.generate( () -> q.poll() )
    .takeWhile(Objects::nonNull) //Note that this is only available in java 9
    .forEach(i -> consume(i));
```

This method is also an example of taking control of what passes the stream. You can manage things like blocking, etc. The `takeWhile` step in this case just shows how the end of the data can be detected.

Comment: I like this solution a lot, you could shorten `() -> q.poll()` to `q::poll` and also the `i  -> consume(i)` to `this::consume` (assuming `consume` is an instance member of a class`)

Comment: Note that `Stream.generate` creates an *unordered* stream, so semantically this is not a correct solution (or at least not identical to the original code), even if it happens to process the elements in the right order in a sequential execution. And it has no advantage over the “archaic” loop anyway…